# Is it possible to use a list as autocompletion basis?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a list like this :

```
MyList<-c("Apple","Banana","Boy","Carry","Crumble",...)
```

I ask the user to enter a word :

```
userWord<-readline("Enter a word: ")
```

The user begins to write :

```
Enter a word: B
```

How would it be possible to make that, when the user presses the `tab`key for example, the words beginning by 'B' (ideally, case insensitive) in `MyList` appear ?

In other words, use `MyList`as a "basis" for autocompletion (whatever the length of the user "beginning of word" is)...

Comment: No. Using `readline` to get user input for R scripts is pretty clunky. There's no mechanism for auto completion (like the kind you can get in an IDE). You can accept a partial answer and show them possible matches iteratively. But it might be worth thinking about building a better interface to the code with something like shiny if that's a priority.

Comment: @MrFlick So this kind of thing is makeable with Shiny ?

Comment: Well, shiny might be overkill but it does have auto complete support for input boxes: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/selectize.html